# Updating Package to Newer Distro (Kinetic)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm now working on Kinetic for the Jetson TX1 and trying out the new builds for aarm64. Everything is working great except I am missing a package that I do not see in the repo nor in the [build farm](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html). Its the [nmea parser](https://github.com/ros-drivers/nmea_navsat_driver).

I can manually pull it down and install, but curious how I can help to submit it to Kinetic. I found a few mentions on how and a detailed answer [here](https://github.com/ros-drivers/nmea_navsat_driver) but I feel there is a submission/vetting process I am missing and haven't been able to find in the wiki other than building [catkin packages](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/CreatingPackage).

What channels do I need to use to ask for a new release?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249602/updating-package-to-newer-distro-(kinetic)/) by [mr337](https://answers.ros.org/users/27943/mr337/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2016-12-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could create an issue asking the maintainers to make a release for Kinetic.
https://github.com/ros-drivers/nmea_navsat_driver/issues

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2016-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mr337](https://answers.ros.org/users/27943/mr337/) on 2016-12-07**:
I wasn't for sure if they checked those. I got a PR open for almost two months with no activity. I'll open an issue.

**Comment by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) on 2016-12-07**:
If that still doesn't work, try mentioning the top committer's names with the @ symbol. That will send them a notification.